# How to make trailing slash optional in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have a django app. In the app I have a url that looks like:-

`path('url/', views.appmain, name="main")`

The problem is that the trailing slash is required. I want to make the slash optional and the url accessible both with or without the slash.
I checked `APPEND_SLASH` but it doesn't work. What's the solution for it.

Comment: As the `APPEND_SLASH` is `True` by default, both `url/` and `url` should point to your `views.appmain` in case that there isn't any url matching your urlconf. Also make sure you have `CommonMiddleware` in your MIDDLEWARES.

Comment: use regular expressions, in `re_path` instead of `path`

Answer (score 12):

You can use `re_path` instead of `path` for use regular expression in your url pattern. use `?` sign in your url like this:

```
from django.urls import re_path
re_path(r'url/?$', views.appmain, name="main")
```

**Note**: question mark matches zero or one `/` in the url. it accepts both `domain.com/url` and `domain.com/url/`

Comment: This doesn't work for me but when I use ```r'url\/?$'``` it works.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to the question, but may save headache for someone with case similar to mine.

Trailing slash is optional by default because of `APPEND_SLASH` setting (if you include `CommonMiddleware`), and it makes Django redirect `'url'` to `'url/'` (if `'url'` is not a valid url pattern itself).
For some specific reasons I needed optional trailing slash without redirect, so I came to `re_path(r'^url/?$', ...)` option mentioned above, and it works. BUT - redirects from `APPEND_SLASH` are 301 Permanent, so for your new url config to start working without redirect, you need to turn on "Disable cache" in browser devtools Networking tab.